# Como sobrescrever o equals para que ele compare: objetos e chaves primitivas (int, String, double)

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, equals

Tem como fazer a comparação de alguma forma? porque no meu código, se não for int ou Object o programa lança uma exceção. Para poder utilizar no método contém da classe ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada.

Classe Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa implements Comparable {

    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa() {
    }

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Pessoa other = (Pessoa) o;

        if (getIdade() < other.getIdade()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (getIdade() > other.getIdade()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Se o objeto for uma instacia de Pessoa, comparar idades entre os dois objetos; ex.: p1.equals(o);
        if (o instanceof Pessoa) {
            return ((Pessoa) o).idade == this.idade;
            //Se a entrada não for um objeto, e sim um inteiro ou String comparar com um atributo de Pessoa; ex.: idade.
        } else if (o != null) {
            int x = (Integer) o; // O problema está aqui, se não for inteiro, o programa lanca uma Exception,
            return x == this.idade; // Tem alguma forma de contornar isso?
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa{" +
                "nome='" + nome + '\'' +
                ", idade=" + idade +
                '}';
    }
}
```

classe ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada implements ILista {

    public Object[] lista;
    public int tamanhoLista;
    public int qtdElementosArmazenados;
    boolean listaInicializada;

    //Vetor extensível.
    public void inicializar(int quantidadeMaxima) {
        lista = new Object[quantidadeMaxima];
        tamanhoLista = quantidadeMaxima;
        qtdElementosArmazenados = 0;
        listaInicializada = true;
    }

    public void adicionar(Comparable o) throws ListaException {
        /**
         * Adicionar em uma posição desejada:
         * for (int i = posElemArmazenado-1; i>=posDesejada; i--){
         *  lista[i+1]=lista[i]
         * lista[r] = e;
         * posElemArmazenado++;
         * }
         */

        if (qtdElementosArmazenados < tamanhoLista) {
            lista[qtdElementosArmazenados] = o;
            qtdElementosArmazenados++;
        } else if (!listaInicializada) {
            throw new ListaException("Lista não inicializada !");
        } else if (qtdElementosArmazenados >= tamanhoLista) {
            throw new ListaException("Lista cheia !");
        }
    }

    public void remover(Object chave) throws ListaException {
        //??? remover um objeto chave ???
        //?remover de uma posicao?
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdElementosArmazenados; i++) {
            if (lista[i].equals(chave)) {
                int pos = i;
                for (int j = pos; j < qtdElementosArmazenados - 1; j++) {
                    lista[j] = lista[j + 1];
                }
                qtdElementosArmazenados--;
            }
        }
    }

    //Como a chave é um objeto, devo utilizar o equals ?!
    //Duvidas nessa parte \/
    public boolean contem(Object chave) throws ListaException {
        if (listaInicializada) {
            for (int i = 0; i < qtdElementosArmazenados; i++) {
                if (lista[i].equals(chave)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new ListaException("Lista nao inicializada !");
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void expandirLista(float percentual) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        //Criar um novo vetor com o novo tamanho, e passar os elementos do anterior para esse.
        //Casos de adidionar um elemento em um indice especificado.

        /*if (qtdElementosArmazenados == tamanhoLista) {*/
        tamanhoLista = ((tamanhoLista * (int) percentual) / 100) + tamanhoLista;
        Object[] listaAuxiliar = new Object[tamanhoLista];
        for (int i = 0; i < qtdElementosArmazenados; i++) {
            listaAuxiliar[i] = lista[i];
        }
        lista = listaAuxiliar;
        /*}*/
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada{" +
                "lista=" + Arrays.toString(lista) +
                ", tamanhoLista=" + tamanhoLista +
                ", qtdElementosArmazenados=" + qtdElementosArmazenados +
                ", listaInicializada=" + listaInicializada +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Classe principal para testes:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ListaException {
    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("lucas",13);
    Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("jose", 14);

    //System.out.println(p1.compareTo(p2));
    //System.out.println(p2.compareTo(p1));

    ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada lista = new ListaSequencialNaoOrdenada();
    lista.inicializar(10);
    //System.out.println(lista);
    lista.adicionar(p1);
    lista.adicionar(p2);
    System.out.println("===============================");
    System.out.println(lista.contem("123123"));
    lista.expandirLista(10);
    //System.out.println(lista);
    lista.expandirLista(10);
    //System.out.println(lista);

    //System.out.println(lista.contem(p1));
    lista.remover(p1);
   // System.out.println(lista);

}
```

}

Comment: Evite apresentar o seu código através de imagens

Comment: Desculpa @Articuno, não sabia como formatar o texto, ai está meu codigo

Comment: Qual o código de teste que você está a utilizar e que geram a exceção ? Como aparte, isso ficaria bem melhor utilizando genéricos

Comment: @Isac poderia passar um tutorial intuitivo sobre generic?: não compreendi muito bem essa forma de implementação.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

```
  @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Pessoa) {
        return ((Pessoa) o).idade == this.idade;
    } else if (o != null) {
        //Parse no valor inteiro para Integer
        return new Integer(this.idade).equals(o);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```